# Flutter - How to display two connected lists in single page?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I want to create a two list sections Upper list and lower list on the same page. Clicking on any one of the upper list item, displays a list associated with it on the lower list pane. How can I implement this?

I have tried following methods but with no luck
1. I tried making lists within a list, but was unable to pass the chosen list details to show it in the lower section.
2. I also tried creating one upper list, assigned a number to it, and then, passed the number (via onTap) to a variable, which would then choose the second list depending upon this given number. I couldn't complete this either.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CustomScrollView` you can learn more in [this article](https://medium.com/flutter/slivers-demystified-6ff68ab0296f).

More about CustomScrollView [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html)

But if you want each list to have an independent scroll, you can use `Column` and the`Expanded` widget

You learn more about `Expanded` widget [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rnZaagadyo)

Sample code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[],
          ),
          flex: 2,//This widget get 2/3 of screen size. Default value is 1
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[],
          ),
          flex: 1,//This widget get 1/3 of screen size
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: While this does give me some insight towards the direction i need to go, I am not certain that this will help me deliver two different lists on one panel, first one being able to call the second one, on press; not scroll as this points out.

Comment: I think understand your problem.
You can use `Column` and add each list inside `Expanded` widget and set weight for each one.
O widget `Expanded` goes expand the max of space available and tell your child that is max viewport.